# Migrate Wiki under Gitlab to ADO Git Wiki Repo

Tags: azure-devops, gitlab, azure-devops-wiki

I am migrating artifacts from GitLab to ADO Git Repo, not able to find much info to migrate the Wikis under GitLab project to ADO repo.

I found below approach to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Step 1 - Clone gitlab wiki

First to clone the Gitlab project, wiki using `git clone https://<gitlab-repo-url>.wiki.git`

- Note we need to include the `wiki.git` at the end of the url, by default the url will be `.git`

The above clone command will download all the wikis to the local.

##### Step 2: Clone ADO Git Repo wiki

Now, from ADO wiki, click the Clone wiki copy the url and use `git clone https://<ado-repo-wiki-url>`

- Better to create a folder and issue the clone command.

##### Step 3: Copy the markdown file from GitLab to ADO Repo

Now, copy the markdown file from the Gitlab cloned directory to the ADO cloned directory.

- In my case there where lots of markdown file, i created a sperate directory and copy pasted the `.md` files.
- The `.md` files had images, which also got downloaded from the Gtilab clone into `uploads` folder.

##### Step 4: Add, commit and push the changes to ADO Git Wiki Repo

Finally, from the ADO git cloned path issues `git add .` and `git commit -m "comments"` then pushed the commits using `git push`.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/wiki-update-offline?view=azure-devops)